# Magento 2 Check if error then redirect to custom url

Tags: magento2, error, redirect, plugin

I am using create post plugin. But the issue with this is, I want to redirect it to a custom URL if an error occurred in `createPost()` default to execute the function.

For example, if a customer with the same email id already exists then it goes in the catch of default `createPost()` execute function's catch. I want to redirect it to my custom page.

Please note, No code to add in try. So try-catch is not used.

Also tried with throw exception but I don't know how to direct with throw exception or with throw it is possible or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can add code then its better to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can add redirect code in Catch section instead of show/print error.

```
try{

   //your logic / code 

}catch{
  
  if error then it comes in catch so,add your redirect code here

}
```